# How to hide price option in layered navigation?

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, product-prices

How to hide price option in layered navigation, while it remains functioning

[image: i want to hide this...]

Answer (score 2):

In Backend, `Catalog->Manage Attributes`.
Check the price attribute and set `Use In Layered Navigation` option `No`

Comment: if I set "NO", the function does not work.

Answer (score 0):

go to `app/design/frontend/yourtherme/default/template/catalog/layer/filter.php`
and chage `<ol>`

to below code

```
<ol <?php

if($this->getName()=='Price' OR  $this->getName()=='price')
{ 

echo 'style="display:none"';
} ?> >
```